# Regular Expression to match C data type

Tags: regex

I have strings like

```
int
int[]
char[]
int[][]
char**
int*
etc
```

I want a regular expression to match this. The best I have been able to come up with is

```
[a-zA-Z]+(\[\])?(\*)?
```

This works for

```
int
int[]
char[]
int[]
int*
char*
```

But validates `int[]*` also and does not validate `int[][]`.

`int`, `char`, etc. are not important and are just examples.

Comment: uh... that actually doesn't seem to work if you are using PCRE: http://regex101.com/r/tS9aY5

Comment: is this really for c data types or just for cases you showed? i think "unsigned char*[]" is also a valid data type.

Comment: And also what do you mean by: _to match **this**_?

Comment: When asking regex questions, please specify the flavor/langauge, because different regex implementations have different abilities and some syntax variations.

Comment: I want to use this in HTML input pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
[a-zA-Z]+((\[\])+|(\*)+)?
```

The `|` operator means "OR." Then the `+` operator means "one or more of the previous." Therefore, the regex means "some letters, then optionally (one or more `[]`s) OR (one or more `*`s)."

#### [Here is a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/krgHC/1/)

Comment: Suggestion: use non-capturing groups instead of capturing groups, might be a little bit faster depending on the regex engine?

Comment: @streetpc I was going to, but since the OP didn't use them I didn't want to complicate it further for him. It really doesn't make a difference anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `?` with `+`. `?`means 0 or 1 time, and `+` at least one time. This to catch multiple `[]` or `*`. Then an alternative should be used `(\[\])+|(\*)+)`

Comment: -1, this validates `int[]*` which the OP says he does not want

Answer (score -1):

This one checks all your posted strings (int int[] char[] int[][] char** int*)

```
[a-zA-Z]+((\[\])*(\*)*)
```

Using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to try it :)

Comment: -1, this validates `int[]*` which the OP says he does not want